# The sentence's object? (pains or Bummer Baskets?)

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've come across with the sentence below:

> One innovative company, Bummer Baskets, sells a range of care
>   packages, each designed to assuage a particular variety of pain,
>   **dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket**

Now, could you tell me please which explanation might be correct:

A:Bummer Baskets is dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket

B: Pains are dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket.

I know the meaning of "Break-Up Basket" but I don't understand the meaning of "dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket". Maybe because I don't recognise the sentence's *object*.

The fuller text is:

> Beyond self-sufficiency and independence, money is also symbolically
>   capable of anesthetizing pain. The Chicago Tribune coined the term
>   retail therapy on Christmas Eve in 1986 to describe the act of trading
>   money for mood-improving purchases, and comfort buying drives the
>   consumption of diverse products from single-serve ice cream to
>   romantic comedies on DVD. One innovative company, Bummer Baskets,
>   sells a range of care packages, each designed to assuage a particular
>   variety of pain, dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket.

*Drunk Tunk Pink* by Adam Alter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a slovenly sentence which leaves it to the reader to figure out from context how the parts hang together.

What the author probably means is that the *range of care packages* is *dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket* — that is, the BUB is the most popular of the care packages and 'dominates' sales in that category.

Comment: I read (or should that be "raid"?) mistakenly the french word for breads there, "pains" (as breads naturally reside in baskets); which made this unholy accretion of words even harder to parse.  It's a basket case, this thing.

Comment: I'd say that's definitely (rather than probably) what the author means. They've gone overboard with the [parenthetical commas](http://drmarkwomack.com/a-writing-handbook/punctuation/commas/parenthetical-commas/), but if you remove all of those you end up with a sentence that should be slightly easier to understand: "One innovative company sells a range of care packages dominated by the chocolate-laden Break-Up Basket."

Answer (score 2):

> Bummer Baskets sells packages.

That is what that sentence says. The object is "care packages". It just adds numerous details via digressions.

Comment: Surely the object is the range of care packages.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it is 'a range of care packages'. I was trying to keep it to the bare minimum in order to show the OP that it is not _pains_ and not the company itself.

Comment: The object is "range". "of care packages" is a prepositional phrase that modifies "range".

Comment: @Acccumulation: The object is the entire phrase "a range of care packages".